# Java: using final keyword only on method parameters that expect immutable objects?

Tags: java, immutability, final

I came across the interesting topic about final method parameters and that they essentially don't provide much advantages. I wondered if it would be sensible to mark only those method parameters as final, when it is advisable to pass an immutable object.

I don't know if this might mislead some people when they're reading the code, because final does not provide this immutability, and even the compiler wouldn't understand that I would like an immutable object to be passed to this method param. But it would be sth like a "human-readable" indicator (especially in APIs) that passing an immutable object is advised.

How would such a concept be evaluated by experienced java programmers?

Comment: Could be useful styling practice within a small team, but this is hardly practical on a larger scale.  I personally would much rather prefer javadoc explicitly stating as such since I'll take clear and verbose over unclear and compact anyday.

Comment: What situation are  you encountering where the type you are receiving may be mutable or immutable?

Comment: I think anyone that understands what Java `final` means (as opposed to e.g. C++'s `const`-ness) would not be mislead by this. The only benefit is it prevents one from reassigning reference parameters inside the method, which _may_ indicate there is a logic error somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I used to use `final` always (these days, from-time-to-time) only to ensure variables are not being re-assigned; nothing more, nothing less.

The advantage of not reassigning variables is *important* to me actually, as it discourages the 'crutch' of temporary variables. This in turn encourages me to re-inspect my code for repetitive code (replacing them with inlined methods, or even to re-structure them) and eliminates potential bugs due to careless re-assignments.

The latter is more helpful in long do-it-all methods, but once broken down into smaller methods, it's easier to see the scope of variables and therefore also to less likely to re-assign them in the first place. Hence my personal preference to use them lesser now.

To address your concern about accepting mutable/immutable objects, my suggestion is to make one the default approach for your library/codebase, stick with that and then document the exception. In other words, if it's better code-wise to be passing immutable objects by default, then you can make that clear so from 'Getting Started'-kind of documentation to address this codebase-wide. You can then make use of [@assylias's](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/288391/119814) suggestion to document the methods to say something like:

```
/**
 *  This method works with mutable arguments as well.
 */
```

Or

```
/**
 *  The side-effect of this method modifies the mutable arguments.
 */
```

You can also play with your classes name by calling them `MyImmutableType` (for example). I generally avoid this as their names don't 'roll well', but YMMV.

```
// this has to return a new MyImmutableType instance
public MyImmutableType doSomething(MyImmutableType input);

// this possibly mutates the mutable argument, which the caller will then use
public void doSomething(MyMutableType input);
```

**Perhaps more importantly**, `final` your arguments' classes too so that if callers/users of your codebase decide to check your source code, then can also immediately tell that the class is immutable.

```
public final class Wrapper<T> {
    private final int id;
    private final T payload;

    public Wrapper(int id, T payload) {
        this.id = id;
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

**In conclusion**, if I see a `final` keyword in the method signature, all I know is that the developer is doing something *right* by not (potentially) reassigning method arguments within the method. It should not be relied upon to indicate whether arguments should/must be be immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea:

- using `final` for a method parameter, as you noticed, does not give any immutability guarantees
- I personally find that it clutters the code unnecessarily
- People using your code should not have to read your code! `final` is not part of the method contract / its javadoc so it is not the right medium to convey information to the callers.

I would rather indicate in the javadoc the assumptions made by the method:

```
/**
 *  This method expects its argument to be immutable
 */
```

ps: I'm not sure *why* you want to receive an immutable object though as it makes no difference for the code in your method (unless you spawn new threads etc.)...